# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hbase, access=EXECUTE, inode="/tmp"

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hbase, cloudera

Hbase error :

> HBase down Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   user=hbase, access=EXECUTE, inode="/tmp":hdfs:supergroup:d-wx------

Answer (score 0):

Solution to above error is Change Permission of tmp directory so hbase user can execute command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /tmp
```

Comment: This assume Hbase user account is part of the hdfs group

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish the `hdfs` user as the hadoop user name to have the execution granted.

`$ export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs`